# Run-time error 3265 Item not found in this collection

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I keep get this run-time 3265 error, said that item not found in the collection for my Sql in the qdf3, I used lots of the methods and it still not work. So I wandering if anyone can take a look at my code and help me out here, Thanks a lot!

```
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Sql1 As String
Dim qdf3 As QueryDef
Dim prm3 As Parameter
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf3 = db.QueryDefs("SELECT [range] From [Query1] WHERE ( [range] ='NA');")
For Each prm3 In qdf3.Parameters
  prm3.Value = Eval(prm3.Name)
Next prm3

Set rs = qdf3.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to why you are trying to set a `QueryDef` to the result of an SQL query, shouldn't the line read more like this:

```
Set qdf3 = db.QueryDefs("queryname")
```

If for some reason `query1` is there to return the name of a query then I suggest determining the appropriate query first and passing it's name to a string, you can then reference this in your querydef call.

---

Also, the final line in the code:

```
Set rs = qdf3.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

I don't think you can set recordsets in this way, I'm not sure why you would want to but perhaps this is more what you are looking for:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(qdf3.Name, dbOpenDynaset)
```